# I try to set if else statement to control the strategy.enter and strategy.exit when 2 or 3 conditions are met. But it didn't

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have 2 issues with the below code. The HedgeSellEnter suppose to take effect after my conditionBuy enter the first position.

1- my HedgeSellEnter did not follow the 3 conditions to enter a position. Instead it keep entering when the first conditions being met.

2- my HedgeSellExit did not follow the 2 conditions to exit a position. My HedgeGap was not calculated even I set the code in HedgeGap := trategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades-1) - strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0)

Thanks.

```
// Strategy - Buy Entry and Exit (5 Mins Chart)
var float HedgeEntry = 0
var float HedgeGap = 0
var float HedgeTarget = 0
var float HedgeTakeProfit = 0
var bool stopLong = false    

// Strategy - Long
if conditionBuy
    strategy.entry("STBUY", strategy.long, qty = lots, comment='Super Buy')
strategy.exit("Exit Buy", "STBUY", profit = longTakeProfit)

HedgeEntry := strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0)
HedgeSellEnter = sellSignal ? dn : na and stopLong != true and strategy.opentrades.size(strategy.opentrades-1) != 0
HedgeSellExit = HedgeTarget > close and stopLong != true

if HedgeSellEnter
    strategy.close("STBUY")
    strategy.order("HEDGESELL", strategy.short, qty = lots*2, comment = 'Enter Hedge Sell')
    HedgeEntry := strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0)
    HedgeGap := strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades-1) - strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0)
    HedgeTarget := strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades-1) - HedgeGap - longGap
else if HedgeSellExit
    strategy.close("HEDGESELL", comment = 'Exit Hedge Sell')
    stopLong := true
```

Comment: for HedgeEntry  what is the purpose of the 'na' in that logic expression?

Comment: This “ sellSignal ? dn : na “ is a signal conditions. To monitor down trend. And this is reflected ok. Only the 2nd and third conditions giving me issue.

Comment: ```HedgeSellEnter = (sellSignal ? dn : na ) and (stopLong != true) and (strategy.opentrades.size(strategy.opentrades-1) != 0)

HedgeSellEnter = {bool?} and bool and bool
```
what is dn? is it bool? 
if dn is bool then this is interpreted as

HedgeSellEnter = sellSignal ? {dn} : {na  and (stopLong != true) and (strategy.opentrades.size(strategy.opentrades-1) != 0)}

and since na is read as 'false' then the rest of the conditions being true will never matter

you might want to write that statement with brackets to be very clear about how you want it to be read

Comment: Understand. Make sense. Let me try to adjust the conditions to remove the conditional ternary operator “? dn : na”. Thanks